# jQuery function to add alpha to element bg

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make function that checks element's bg and changes its bg to have given alpha channel. Function has this form:

```
$.fn.bgalpha = function(alpha) {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    //...
}
```

But: chrome returns bg as rgb when normal color is set and as rgba with zero's when there is no bg, ie 8 always returns hex, ie9 returns 'transparent' when there is no bg and rgb when there is bg etc. So much different cases.

What I want to do is > get r,g,b from bg color of object, add to it 'a' channel and set element bg as rgba with all the values. But from simple thing to do it's getting tricky and complicated when we talk about cross-browsing.

Have you any idea how to operate with those colors some 'uniwersal' way?
In different cases I get values 'none', 'transparent', 'rgba', 'rgb' or 'hex' as initial value of bg

Comment: This is probably a lot simpler than it sounds. If the browser returns hex as color, it probably does'nt support rgb, and not all browsers do. Not all browsers support rgba either, and you can't set the Alpha channel if the browser does'nt support rgba, so you need to start by testing if the browser supports rgba, if it does, just set the color with rgba !

Comment: How about a workaround: use two elements, layered on top of each other, one with the background and one with the content. Then just change the opacity of the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) (it's officially sanctioned) and use its `.alpha()` method.

The following code snippet will change the background color of `this` so it's 50% transparent:

```
var clr2 = $.Color(this,'background-color').alpha(0.5);
$(this).css('background-color', clr2.toRgbaString());
```

or as one line:

```
$(this).css('background-color', $.Color(this,'background-color').alpha(0.5).toRgbaString());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aea3h/

Comment: Not really. Depends what you want to achieve. I've trimmed it down.

Comment: got red-bg #lol div, make $('#lol').bgalpha(0.5); and have its bg 50% transparent, thats it.

Comment: Not sure what that means, sorry.

Comment: I think that's because I'm using `this` in my code snippet, and you haven't defined `this`. Replace `this` with whatever HTML element or jQuery object you're altering. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pqu94/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.bgalpha = function(alpha)
{
    return $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', $.Color(this,'background-color').alpha(alpha).toRgbaString());          
    });
}
```

Using [Blazemonger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032998/901048) solution - this is final code.

Using:

```
$('.something').bgalpha(0.8);
```

And it requires `jquery.color.js` (7kb after minifing)